# Incrementing/decrementing a number in a file from a ( zsh ) script

Tags: files, zsh

From a script ( running multiple times simultaneously ), I would like create a file something like:

```
echo "0" > /tmp/count
```

Then I would like to do three functions.

```
incr /tmp/count
decr /tmp/count
is_zero /tmp/count
```

which do thje fairly obvious thing: increment the value in /tmp/count, decrement the value in /tmp/count and test if the value is_zero.

I can write three C programs to do this, but am hoping that there already exists a way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
incr() {
    var=$(< "$1")
    var=$((var + 1))
    echo $var > "$1"
}

is_zero() {
    var=$(< "$1")
    [[ var -eq 0 ]]
}
```

`decr` is left as an exercise for the reader.